# How to extend GenericRepository?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DbContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

I want to create MemberRepository which is extended by GenericRepository.

So I tried like this,

```
public class MemberRepository<Member> : GenericRepository<Member> where Member : class
    {
        public MemberRepository(DbContext context) : base(context){}

        public IQueryable<Member> GetMemberList(SearchOptions options)
        {
            IQueryable<Member> query = dbSet;

            query = query.Where(x= > x.name == "test"); //!!
        }
```

but I can not search by name, the error message say,

> Member does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension
>   method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Member' could be
>   found.

But the Member class contain name and it's public.

I think the way extend generic is something wrong.

What am I doing wrong? please give me an advice.

Here is my Member class,

```
[Table("member")]
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int schoolId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("schoolId")]
    public School school { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you also add ,the Member class definition to your quesionn

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler I just added the Member class, could you please take a look?

Comment: is the intellisense showing `name` property on `x`? If not can you tell us what object you are getting on `x`.

Comment: Well the problem is that you declared your MemberRepository class wrong. it should be like this `public class MemberRepository : GenericRepository<Member>` . If you add a MemberRepository<Member> you get a generic parameter which is called Member and the only constraint you add is that it has to be a class. So the compiler does not know anything about it except that it is a class

Comment: @PonasJustas Now I understand, thank you for your description!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you generics is a bit mismatch with the name of the Member and a generic parameter class this should fix the issue

```
public class MemberRepository : GenericRepository<Member>
```

Comment: hehe, just what i wrote in the comments :)